# Make select option selected based on an unordered list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, selection

I've converted my unordered list into a select option list, however I'm not sure how can I make the 'selected' attribute added the option which correlates to the same hyperlink in the list.

Mark-up

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
         <li><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
         <li><a href="bar.html" class="selected">Bar</a></li>
         <li><a href="boo.html">Boo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('<select />').appendTo('.navigation');

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$('.navigation ul a').each(function() {
 var el = $(this);
 $('<option />', {
    "value"   : el.attr('href'),
    "text"    : el.text()
 }).appendTo('.navigation select');
});
// Navigate to page on select option
$('.navigation select').change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
});
// Hide navigation list
$('.navigation ul').hide();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `hasClass` method:

```
 $('<option />', {
    "value"      : el.attr('href'),
    "text"       : el.text(),
    "selected"   : el.hasClass('selected')
 }).appendTo('.navigation select');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5V5rY/

Answer (score -1):

You seem to dynamically create the select element .

So you need to **delegate the event** to the `closest static parent` container to let it work..

```
$('.navigation select').change(function() {
```

supposed to be

```
$('.navigation').on('change', 'select',function() {
```

Also to select the value you can just do `.val();`

```
window.location = $(this).val();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, but thanks for your input on the other part of my code.